# wpdb->insert producing duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to make a button on a page that prints out data from the database and then you can press 2 different buttons, one that deletes them from the database and the other one inserts it into another table in the database and deletes the data from the database, but it keeps inserting it twice into the new table and I have no clue why, this here prints out the data and session variables + buttons:

```
if(!isset($_POST['orderby'])) {
  foreach ($requests as $row) {
    echo "<div class='requests'>" . "<li class='refunds'>" . "Palauttajan nimi: ".
    $row['customer_name'] . "</br>" ."Palautettavat tuotteet: ".$row['product_name']."<br> "."Määrä: ".
    $row['product_qty'] . " "
    . "<br>Kommentti: " . $row['comment'] . "<br> " . "Hinta: " . $row['refund_total'] . "€ " .
    "<br>" . "Päivämäärä: " . $row['request_date'] . " " .
    "<a class='right' href='admin-page?deleteid=" . $row['request_id'] . "'>Hylkää</a></li>" .
    "<li class='refundaccepts'><a href='admin-page?acceptid=" . $row['request_id']
    . "'>Hyväksy</a></li>" . "</div>";
    $_SESSION['custname'] = $row['customer_name'];
    $_SESSION['prodname'] = $row['product_name'];
    }
  } else {
    foreach ($pergele as $row) {
      echo "<div class='requests'>" . "<li class='refunds2'>" . "Palauttajan nimi: ".
      $row['customer_name'] . "</br>" ."Palautettavat tuotteet: ".$row['product_name']."<br> "."Määrä: ".
      $row['product_qty'] . " "
      . "<br>Kommentti: " . $row['comment'] . "<br> " . "Hinta: " . $row['refund_total'] . "€ " .
      "<br>" . "Päivämäärä: " . $row['request_date'] . " " .
      "<a class='right' href='admin-page?deleteid=" . $row['request_id'] . "'>Hylkää</a></li>" .
      "<li class='refundaccepts'><a href='admin-page?acceptid=" . $row['request_id']
      . "'>Hyväksy</a></li>" . "</div>";
      $_SESSION['custname'] = $row['customer_name'];
      $_SESSION['prodname'] = $row['product_name'];
    }
  }
```

and this should insert it into the database once and delete the data from the old table:

```
 if(isset($_GET['acceptid'])) {
   $accept = $_GET['acceptid'];
   $custname = $_SESSION['custname'];
   $prodname = $_SESSION['prodname'];
   /* Query to do whatever here */
   $wpdb->insert("wp_acceptedrequests", [
      "customer_name" => "$custname",
      "name_product" => "$prodname",
      "date" => date("Y/m/d/G:i:sa") ,
  ]);
  $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_refundrequests WHERE request_id = $accept");

  }
```

What makes them insert twice and how do I prevent it from doing that?

Comment: as per the code posted by you it wont insert 2 times, might be you missed something

Comment: I added the entire `if(isset)` into the original post instead of only the foreach.

Comment: You should never use `GET` request to manipulate data. Additionally, try to check where the insert calls occur to see whether you call such a method twice

Comment: What can I use to check if it occurs twice? and should I use `POST` instead of  `GET` then?

Comment: Checked for errors and it should only insert data once there are no signs of a double insert

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar situation where $wpdb inserts where being duplicated.
In my case it was happening if I was authenticated and browser inspector was open.